# Magnetic field and magnetic forces and polarity

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, voltage

When the polarity of the voltage applied to a DC motor is reversed, the direction of motion does not reversed. Why not? How could the direction of motion be reversed?

Answer (score 0):

In an ordinary (permanent magnet) DC motor, reversing the drive polarity will indeed reverse the direction of rotation of the motor. This principle is used in all reversible battery-powered electric screwdrivers, etc. This will not happen if the motor is an AC type.

Answer (score 0):

You have a shunt or compound motor.

[image: Shunt Motor]

The field winding is in parallel with the armature.

There are four terminals:

- armature A1 and A2.
- shunt field F1 and F2.

If you reverse the source V, all currents reverse but the motor goes in the same direction.  Field and armature reverse.

To reverse the motor, you must switch the polarity of the field or the armature.